# Changing Column header name of ListView using vb.net code

Tags: vb.net

I have a listview with several columns.  I want to change the column header using code.
Please advise how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView ColumnHeader.Name is empty string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120354/listview-columnheader-name-is-empty-string)

Comment: @JonH Not a duplicate. Name and Text are two different things, Mr. H.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested `ListView1.Columns(0).Text = "changed"` and it worked. This is VB.Net, winforms, VS 2010.

Comment: It's not very intuitive. HeaderText would have made more sense as a property name. I thought it used to be called that, so I had to look around for it. Happy to help, man. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In a List View, there is a difference between
Column Header .Name and Column Header .Text.

The .Text is displayed at the top of the List View.
The .Name is the Column Name which you can refer to in your code.
If you try to get the ListView1.Columns(0).Name in your code, it will always be "".
Unless, during the design time, in the edit column header properties,
you set Under Data, Application Settings, and Properties Binding,
the DisplayIndex Name Default Value is the .Name value.

[ColumnHeader Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo2Z5.png)

Answer (score -1):

To change the header name, you have to use the name property

```
Listview1.columns(0).name = "column1Name"
```

But you can also assign the column name while assigning it's "text" value

```
Listview1.Columns.add("Column1text").name = "Column1Name"
```

You can then use it's name to refer to it

```
    Listview1.columns.item(Listview1.columns("Column1Name").index).text = "Column1TextChanged"
```